# How to continue a loop using PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops

I want to continue my looping. But it does not continue once the first process not found.
This is my code.

```
function Capture
{
     ##some process##     
     Write-Host "Capture"
     Start-Sleep -s 1

}

function error
{
     ##some process##
     write-host "error function"
     write-host "error function2"
     write-host "error function3"
     Capture

     Exit

}

String = @('The Student Name is','Data Member')
try 
{
     foreach ($str in $String )
     {
          $Bio = Get-Content ".\DUMP1.log" -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {$_ -like "*$str*"}         
          if ($null -eq $Bio)
          {

               Write-Host "not found"
               error
               continue
          }
          return $Bio                    
     }
}
catch 
{
     $msg = "Bio Not Found`n" + $_
     $ExitCode = "133"
     Exit $ExitCode    
}
```

If the first array not exist in the DUMP.log file, then it stop the process, it does not continue to check the second array.
My expectation is, once the first array can not found, then check the second array, after all the array checking not found, then the process will continue to `error` function. But The process will not go to `error` function as long as the process still not checking all the array.

Anyone can help please. Thank you

Comment: You need to put the `try/catch` block inside the `foreach` loop body if you want to continue the loop on error

Comment: I tried, but stiill not continue the process @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: That's probably because you `exit` from the `catch` block. So what do you want to do? Exit or continue on failure? Can't have it both ways :)

Comment: I tried to remove the try/catch and the process still stop, can not continue 
I add some explanation about my expectation above. Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen